# Simple status message implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, class, properties

I'm trying to create basic class which will allow different controls to bind-in and display some values.

I want to have static list of objects, where each object has some properties like caption, ticks counter, whatever.

Then I want to bind label to last added item to this list and datagridview to allow to see all of them.

Would be great if such solution could be for both winforms and wpf environments.

If you could point me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Draft of the idea (one of many already tested and failed) below.

status class:

```
public class Status: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    //implementation of observable collection
    private static ObservableCollection<Status> _list;
    public static ObservableCollection<Status> List
    {
        get { return _list ?? (_list = new ObservableCollection<Status>{new Status()}); }
    }

    //object properties
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }

    //object views
    public string View
    {
        get { return Message + "(" + Finished + ")" ; }
    }

    //object methods
    public static Status Add(string message)
    {
        var result = new Status
        {
            Message = message,
            Finished = false
        };

        List.Add(result);
        return result;
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        Finished = true;
    }
}
```

form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Status.List, "Message");
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "View";
        listBox1.DataSource = Status.List;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label5.Text  = Status.Add(textBox1.Text).Message;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Status)listBox1.SelectedItem).Finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WindowsFormsApplication2.Annotations;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #region Notyfier implementation
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    #region collection implemetation

    public BindingList<Item> Items = new BindingList<Item>();

    public string Count
    {
        get { return (Items.Count == 1) 
            ? "1 item." 
            : Items.Count + " items."; }
    }

    public Item Current
    {
        get { return Items.Count == 0 
            ? new Item {Colour = Color.Chartreuse} //default initial item
            : Items.Last(); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region object implemetation

    protected object ID { get; set; }
    public Color Colour { get; set; }

    public void NewItem(Color color)
    {
        Items.Add(new Item
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(), 
                Colour = color
            });

        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        OnPropertyChanged("Current");
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```